# GeoServer, WFS Raise java.io.IOException: Wrong magic number, expected 9994, got 15

Tags: geoserver, wfs

The "WFS_transactionInsert.xml" demo request in "GeoServer Demos" results into:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Wrong magic number, expected 9994, got 15
```

The complete exception message is :

```
2020-01-07 15:51:23,811 WARN [geoserver.catalog] - Error while getting feature type, flushing cache and retrying: java.io.IOException: Wrong magic number, expected 9994, got 15
2020-01-07 15:51:23,812 ERROR [geoserver.ows] - 
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Wrong magic number, expected 9994, got 15
    at org.geotools.data.store.ContentFeatureSource.getAbsoluteSchema(ContentFeatureSource.java:329)
    at org.geotools.data.store.ContentFeatureSource.getSchema(ContentFeatureSource.java:296)
    at org.geotools.data.store.ContentDataStore.getSchema(ContentDataStore.java:291)
    at org.geotools.data.directory.DirectoryDataStore.getSchema(DirectoryDataStore.java:99)
    at org.geotools.data.directory.DirectoryDataStore.getSchema(DirectoryDataStore.java:163)
    at org.geotools.data.directory.DirectoryDataStore.getSchema(DirectoryDataStore.java:50)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.ResourcePool.getCacheableFeatureType(ResourcePool.java:923)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.ResourcePool.tryGetFeatureType(ResourcePool.java:902)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.ResourcePool.getFeatureType(ResourcePool.java:894)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.ResourcePool.getFeatureType(ResourcePool.java:879)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.impl.FeatureTypeInfoImpl.getFeatureType(FeatureTypeInfoImpl.java:123)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor242.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.impl.ModificationProxy.invoke(ModificationProxy.java:127)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy27.getFeatureType(Unknown Source)
    at org.geoserver.wfs.xml.FeatureTypeSchemaBuilder.isSimpleFeature(FeatureTypeSchemaBuilder.java:391)
    at org.geoserver.wfs.xml.FeatureTypeSchemaBuilder.buildSchemaInternal(FeatureTypeSchemaBuilder.java:195)
    at org.geoserver.wfs.xml.FeatureTypeSchemaBuilder.addApplicationTypes(FeatureTypeSchemaBuilder.java:545)
    at org.geoserver.wfs.xml.v1_0_0.WFS.buildSchema(WFS.java:221)
    at org.geotools.xsd.XSD.getSchema(XSD.java:186)
    at org.geotools.xsd.SchemaLocator.locateSchema(SchemaLocator.java:86)
    at org.geotools.xsd.impl.ParserHandler.startElement(ParserHandler.java:416)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.geotools.xsd.Parser.parse(Parser.java:251)
    at org.geotools.xsd.Parser.parse(Parser.java:199)
    at org.geoserver.wfs.xml.v1_0_0.WfsXmlReader.read(WfsXmlReader.java:75)
    at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.parseRequestXML(Dispatcher.java:1606)
    at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.dispatch(Dispatcher.java:700)
    at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.handleRequestInternal(Dispatcher.java:254)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:177)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:52)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:998)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:901)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:875)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:873)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1623)
    at org.geoserver.filters.ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.doFilter(ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.java:26)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:69)
    at org.geoserver.wms.animate.AnimatorFilter.doFilter(AnimatorFilter.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:66)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
    at org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter.doFilter(AdvancedDispatchFilter.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:51)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:215)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:52)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
    at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.java:142)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
    at org.geoserver.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
    at org.geoserver.filters.XFrameOptionsFilter.doFilter(XFrameOptionsFilter.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
    at org.geoserver.filters.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter.doFilter(SessionDebugFilter.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
    at org.geoserver.filters.FlushSafeFilter.doFilter(FlushSafeFilter.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1602)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1700)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1345)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:480)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1667)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1247)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:505)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:267)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:305)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:333)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:366)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:698)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:804)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Wrong magic number, expected 9994, got 15
    at org.geotools.data.shapefile.shp.ShapefileHeader.checkMagic(ShapefileHeader.java:59)
    at org.geotools.data.shapefile.shp.ShapefileHeader.read(ShapefileHeader.java:79)
    at org.geotools.data.shapefile.shp.ShapefileReader.init(ShapefileReader.java:346)
    at org.geotools.data.shapefile.shp.ShapefileReader.(ShapefileReader.java:276)
    at org.geotools.data.shapefile.ShapefileSetManager.openShapeReader(ShapefileSetManager.java:48)
    at org.geotools.data.shapefile.ShapefileFeatureSource.readAttributes(ShapefileFeatureSource.java:520)
    at org.geotools.data.shapefile.ShapefileFeatureSource.buildFeatureType(ShapefileFeatureSource.java:479)
    at org.geotools.data.shapefile.ShapefileFeatureStore.buildFeatureType(ShapefileFeatureStore.java:137)
    at org.geotools.data.store.ContentFeatureSource.getAbsoluteSchema(ContentFeatureSource.java:327)
    ... 137 more
```

The version of GeoServer that I am using is 2.15.3

Answer (score 2):

GeoServer is trying to read the shapefile, and finds that the header of the shapefile is not following the specification, but looks like something else.
Hyphotesis:

- The file in question is not really a Shapefile
- The file looks like a Shapefile, but it has been encoded in a way that does not follow the Shapefile headers

See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures

Comment: The file is a valid shapefile I am using two different shapefiles one from default shapefiles which comes with geoserver and another one downloaded from OSM official.
I tried with different type of data sources (shapefile and postgis) but the result was the same.
However the encoding is not "ISO-8859-1" because I couldn't decode it to human readeble text.

Comment: Can you provide a URL where that OSM official shapefile can be downloaded?

Answer (score 1):

Shapefiles might get corrupted while downloading/transferring. In our case, we had the file checked out from git and experienced the same issue

```
java.io.IOException: Wrong magic number, expected 9994, got 9997
```

Force resetting the file resolved this issue.

```
git checkout HEAD -- my-shapefile.shx
```

In this case, it seems like the shapefile was read from a WFS, maybe it is lying corrupted on the source system.